# How to get text from each line from TextInput in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to extract the text from each line in TextInput.

For example, we have a TextInput with text="Hello I came from the earth and my name is" like this:

[image]

and the output will be: ["Hello I came from the","earth and my name is"]

And when we resize it smaller like this:

[image]

we will get the output: ["Hello I came","from the earth","and my name is"]

I tried the "_lines" function, but it is not really accurate when sometimes it gives the wrong len(lines) or wrong words in each line.

So I wonder if there is any way to determine those? Or maybe I can get the TextInput's texture_size, but I don't think TextInput support that.

Comment: The (internal) attribute `_lines` should do the job. Can you please post a minimal example that fails to do that ?

Comment: @ApuCoder Turns out, I was using the function _lines in the wrong way. It's such a shame, thanks for your comment that make me realize my mistake. I'll post an answer for this right now.

Answer (score 0):

ApuCoder was right, the function _lines is the best way to solve this kind of question, here is the complete code to answer this question.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = '''
<Input>:
    id: input
'''

class Input(TextInput):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        Window.bind(on_keyboard=self._on_keyboard_down)
    
    """_lines function"""
    def validate(self):
        lines = [i for i in self._lines]
        print(lines)
    
    """Just a function for easier test (enter=validate),(shift/ctrl+enter=down the line)"""
    def _on_keyboard_down(self, instance, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if keycode == 40 and (modifiers == ["numlock","ctrl"] or modifiers == ["shift","numlock"]):
            return
        if keyboard == 13:
            self.focus=False
            self.validate()

"""App running"""
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.kv = Builder.load_string(kv)
        return Input()
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```